# Xamarin- StreamWriter

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

I need to write a new line to Tabulka.txt but its only Rewriting can you help me ?

```
        StreamWriter srt = new StreamWriter(System.IO.Path.Combine(path, "Tabulka.txt"));

        srt.WriteLine(Intent.GetStringExtra("ulozeno"));
        srt.Close();
        StreamReader srt2 = new StreamReader(System.IO.Path.Combine(path, "Tabulka.txt"));
        text2.Text = text2.Text + srt2.ReadToEnd();
        srt2.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
StreamWriter srt = new StreamWriter(System.IO.Path.Combine(path, "Tabulka.txt"),append:true);
```